# Scaling a user-unique real-time ranking algorithm

Tags: database, algorithm, scalability

so I've spent all of today and yesterday working on a ranking algorithm for a messaging app that I'm working on and now I'm trying to figure out how to handle all of the calls to this algorithm. The app is structured into rooms and the main news feed shows certain rooms based on this:

```
num_mutual_friends * weight_f + ln(density + 1) * weight_d
----------------------------------------------------------
  (ln(dist + 1) / 3) * weight_d + ln(time + 1) * weight_t
```

I'm trying to think about how to scale performing this operation on millions of database entries. A lot of the variables require unique queries to the database (number of mutual friends, for example, is different for each pair of users), and others are dependent upon the current state of the user (e.g. distance, time) or room (e.g. density).

I'm thinking it's inefficient to have to query for every single room and then iterate through all of them, assigning scores and then choosing the top x rooms every time someone refreshes their feed.

My first thought was to limit the query by cutting off values after a certain point – for example, the algorithm wouldn't have to look through rooms whose location is > x distance away from the user's current distance or rooms whose last activity was over x months ago.

However, I want to be able to still return rooms if those limitations that I set end up not having enough results.

How do you scale something like this? I can't really cache results from queries because they change all the time – any help, guidelines, or good things to read about scalability would be appreciated

Comment: How many rooms are there? How many "friends" are in them? How many users are there? You are right in that this is a hard problem. Probably you need to approximate and cache.